# Qual é a função do 'do' statement?

Tags: lua

O que o `'do'` sozinho espera e faz?

```
do
   ...
end
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Faz nada :)

Ele inicia um bloco de comandos que devem ser executados em conjunto. O bloco obviamente é terminado pelo `end`.

É muito comum usar com comando, tais como: `if` (na verdade usa o `then` no lugar do `do`), `while`, `for` e funções (ainda que neste caso o `do` é implícito), onde é comum ter várias linhas.

É importante notar que ele gera escopo, então as variáveis criadas nele só existem dentro dele. Então ele pode ser usado só para gerar escopo.

```
do
    local x = 1
    y = x + 1
end
print(y) -- não poderia mandar imprimir x
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Lua/Do.lua).

Em linguagens chamadas *C-like*, como o JavaScript, PHP, Java, C#, etc. ele seria o equivalente ao abre chave `{`, assim como o `end` seria o fecha chave `}`.

[Página com tutorial e exemplos](http://lua-users.org/wiki/ControlStructureTutorial).

Comment: Quando crio uma variável em um statement sem "do" ou "then" (caso if) declarado então a variável é global no bloco atual - foi o que entendi. Isso é certo?

Comment: Isso é outra coisa. Todas variáveis são globais a não ser que sejam declaradas como locais. O escopo local é definido por algumas regras que determinam o bloco de comandos.

Comment: Hum... todos os blocos de comando no Lua geram escopos, certo? No ECMAScript os blocos não geram escopo novo de variáveis, só funções, porém as declarações `const` e `let` definem variáveis no próprio bloco.

Answer (score 3):

A principal função e a utilidade do `do` é criar um escopo novo: variáveis locais definidas dentro desse escopo não escapam para fora dele.

Uma razão para usar um escopo novo é não poluir o resto do programa.

Uma razão mais sofisticada é para criar e manter estado privado:

```
do
  local n=0
   function count() n=n+1 print(n) end
end
```

`count` é visível fora do escopo mas `n` não.

Answer (score 2):

Você deveria usar essa sequência logo depois de um while. Ela serve para limitar o trecho de código que será executado dentro do loop.

Por exemplo:

```
a=10

while( a < 20 ) 
do    
print("valor de a:", a)    
a = a+1 
end
```